# not all arguments converted during string formatting. flask restful api

Tags: python

i write this query in my flask restful api when i hit it from postman this shows the error mentioned on top.
not all arguments converted during string formatting

```
cur.execute('''DELETE FROM `students`.`std_record`
                WHERE `roll_num` = %s;''', (roll_num))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have improperly formatted the variable you want to pass (currently it supplies a list of the characters of `roll_num`), it should be passed as a tuple (containing one item), like so:

```
cur.execute('''DELETE FROM `students`.`std_record`
            WHERE `roll_num` = %s;''', (roll_num,))
```